# Why are 5v capacitors so much more expensive than 50v capacitors?

Tags: capacitor

Why are 5v capacitors so much more expensive than 50v capacitors?  Are they harder to manufacture? It seems the lower the voltage the harder it is to find.

Comment: What values and capacitor technology are you dealing with here?

Comment: You'd better point out some examples. If you look at ceramic SMT parts in the 1 uF and up range, and smaller sizes, then 6.3 V is really common.

Comment: I'm just trying to buy parts on ebay and aliexpress. Maybe I'm an idiot and searching wrong. I don't need a super cap. Just something at 5v.

Comment: It depends A LOT on the actual capacitance value.  Low value capacitors are made in 50V because it isn't any cheaper to make them in lower values. And typically it isn't much smaller, either, so there isn't any point to it.  Your question CANNOT BE ANSWERED unless you cite specific capacitance values you are looking for. Else it is NOT a valid generic question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capacitor rated at 50V on a lower voltage such as 5V, so unless there is some advantage (size or cost, typically) in making the lower voltage rating, a higher one is to be preferred.

For example, it would be unusual for a 100pF NP0 ceramic capacitor to be rated at only 5V.

Comment: it would be impossible to find that , as you know

Answer (score 1):

A cap rated for 5V implies that it has exceptionally low voltage breakdown , high capacitance and very low ESR or very high density (small size)

Realize that Voltage is not an indicator of cost unless you know that it implies an ultracap or an ultralow ESR cap.

---

### 5F @5V = $10 [image]